# Reset tic tac toe in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple tic tac toe game for a project. My issue is that I don't understand how to reset the game in order to play a new game. I was able to clear the board with success using a button, and I would like to have the game reset using this button. The button is associated with an input id of "btnClear." Thanks in advance.

```
$(function(){

    var o = "<img src='o.png'/>";
    var x = "<img src='x.png'/>";
    var player = 1;
    var p1Arr = new Array();
    var p2Arr = new Array();

    function win(currentPlayer){
        currentPlayer = currentPlayer.sort();
        

        if(currentPlayer.includes("td0") && currentPlayer.includes("td1") && currentPlayer.includes("td2")){

            alert("Player " + player + " is the winner!!")
            $("td").unbind("click");
            $("#td3").empty();
            $("#td4").empty();
            $("#td5").empty();
            $("#td6").empty();
            $("#td7").empty();
            $("#td8").empty();

        } else if(currentPlayer.includes("td0") && currentPlayer.includes("td3") && currentPlayer.includes("td6")){

            alert("Player " + player + " is the winner!!")
            $("td").unbind("click");
            $("#td1").empty();
            $("#td2").empty();
            $("#td4").empty();
            $("#td5").empty();
            $("#td7").empty();
            $("#td8").empty();

        } else if(currentPlayer.includes("td0") && currentPlayer.includes("td4") && currentPlayer.includes("td8")){

            alert("Player " + player + " is the winner!!")
            $("td").unbind("click");
            $("#td1").empty();
            $("#td2").empty();
            $("#td3").empty();
            $("#td5").empty();
            $("#td6").empty();
            $("#td7").empty();
            
        } else if(currentPlayer.includes("td3") && currentPlayer.includes("td4") && currentPlayer.includes("td5")){

            alert("Player " + player + " is the winner!!")
            $("td").unbind("click");
            $("#td0").empty();
            $("#td1").empty();
            $("#td2").empty();
            $("#td6").empty();
            $("#td7").empty();
            $("#td8").empty();
            
        } else if(currentPlayer.includes("td6") && currentPlayer.includes("td7") && currentPlayer.includes("td8")){

            alert("Player " + player + " is the winner!!")
            $("td").unbind("click");
            $("#td0").empty();
            $("#td1").empty();
            $("#td2").empty();
            $("#td3").empty();
            $("#td4").empty();
            $("#td5").empty();
            
        } else if(currentPlayer.includes("td1") && currentPlayer.includes("td4") && currentPlayer.includes("td7")){

            alert("Player " + player + " is the winner!!")
            $("td").unbind("click");
            $("#td0").empty();
            $("#td2").empty();
            $("#td3").empty();
            $("#td5").empty();
            $("#td6").empty();
            $("#td8").empty();
            
        } else if(currentPlayer.includes("td2") && currentPlayer.includes("td5") && currentPlayer.includes("td8")){

            alert("Player " + player + " is the winner!!")
            $("td").unbind("click");
            $("#td0").empty();
            $("#td1").empty();
            $("#td3").empty();
            $("#td4").empty();
            $("#td6").empty();
            $("#td7").empty();
            
        } else if(currentPlayer.includes("td2") && currentPlayer.includes("td4") && currentPlayer.includes("td6")){

            alert("Player " + player + " is the winner!!")
            $("td").unbind("click");
            $("#td0").empty();
            $("#td1").empty();
            $("#td3").empty();
            $("#td5").empty();
            $("#td7").empty();
            $("#td8").empty();
            
        }

    }

    $("td").click(function(){
        
        if(player == 1){
            $(this).html(x);
            $(this).unbind("click");
            p1Arr.push(this.id);
            win(p1Arr);
            player = 2;
        } else {
            $(this).html(o);
            $(this).unbind("click");
            p2Arr.push(this.id);
            win(p2Arr);
            player = 1;
        }
    })

        $("#btnClear").click(function(){
        
            $("#td0").empty();
            $("#td1").empty();
            $("#td2").empty();
            $("#td3").empty();
            $("#td4").empty();
            $("#td5").empty();
            $("#td6").empty();
            $("#td7").empty();
            $("#td8").empty();

        });
    
})
```

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML in order to test the game? I believe you have to reset variables too. E.g. player = 1, p1Arr = new Array(), p2Arr = new Array(). When you click #btnClear

Comment: Can you share rest of your code on codesandbox or similar platform ?

Comment: @TomaszKisiel keeping code is on-site is better for the lifespan of the question. Look for the `<>` icon the question editor to make a *stack snippet*

Comment: Off-topic to your question: look into using loops and caching values. Looping can help you to write code much faster so you don't have to repeat any lines. Caching values will improve the performance of your site by looking for elements once and storing them in variables which you can reference later. Every time you call `$('#td0')`, you search for the element `<td id="td0">`. Saving the result of that call `const $td0 = $('#td0')`, and using the value of the variable instead will save you a lot of the same searches on the page.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the button, you reset the board but not the variables. All you need to do is set the variables to their original values and bind onclick functions to the buttons again. BTW, the code can surely be written better (e.g. copying the onclick function - I am sure you can just call a predefined function) but my knowledge of jQuery isn't so great and I don't want to mislead you.

```
$("td").click(() => {
    if (player == 1){
        $(this).html(x);
        $(this).unbind("click");
        p1Arr.push(this.id);
        win(p1Arr);
        player = 2;
    } else {
        $(this).html(o);
        $(this).unbind("click");
        p2Arr.push(this.id);
        win(p2Arr);
        player = 1;
    }
});

$("#btnClear").click(function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        $("#td" + i).empty();

    $("td").click(() => {
        if (player == 1){
            $(this).html(x);
            $(this).unbind("click");
            p1Arr.push(this.id);
            win(p1Arr);
            player = 2;
        } else {
            $(this).html(o);
            $(this).unbind("click");
            p2Arr.push(this.id);
            win(p2Arr);
            player = 1;
        }
    });

    player = 1;
    p1Arr = new Array();
    p2Arr = new Array();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After I submitted the first answer, I got an idea that you could just call the function again. I wanted to make this answer short so you have to paste the original code from the function without the #btnClear onclick function in the place where the one-line comment is.

```
function game() {
    // Paste your original function code here but with this #btnClear onclick function:
    $("#btnClear").click(function() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            $("#td" + i).empty();

        return game();
    });
}

$(function() { game(); });
```